# Temp table is not a known variable

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

I've got a temp table which I want to use twice to insert into it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test1(user_id BIGINT) RETURNS BIGINT AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table1;
  create temp table temp_table1
  on commit drop
  as select * from get_some_data($1); -- try to get the data for the 1st time

  if not exists (select * temp_table1) then
    select try_to_update_data($1); -- updates data, returns void
  end if;

  -- try to get the data again
  select * into temp_table1 from get_some_data($1); -- error!
  if not exists (select * from temp_table1) then
    return 0;
  end if;

  --........ use temp_table1
```

It trows the error:

```
ERROR:  "temp_table1" is not a known variable
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

write `INSERT INTO temp_table1 SELECT get_some_data($1);`

in place of what you had

`select * into temp_table1 from get_some_data($1); -- error!`

May be this will work for you.

Comment: This worked for me. Mind explaining why the `INSERT INTO` approach didn't work? Syntax seems sound.

Answer (score 2):

> *RowanStone is looking for a more detailed answer to this question.*

The reason the SELECT INTO does not work is because there are two contexts to execute it and `SELECT INTO TABLE` in not available in PL/pgSQL:

[SELECT INTO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-selectinto.html):

> ```
> SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT [ ON ( expression [, ...] ) ] ]
>      * | expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...]
> INTO [ TEMPORARY | TEMP | UNLOGGED ] [ TABLE ] new_table
> ```

> **CREATE TABLE AS is functionally similar to SELECT INTO. CREATE TABLE AS is the recommended syntax, since this form of SELECT INTO is not available in
> ECPG or PL/pgSQL, because they interpret the INTO clause differently.**

---

[43.5.3. Executing a Command with a Single-Row Result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)

> **The result of an SQL command yielding a single row (possibly of multiple columns) can be assigned to a record variable, row-type variable, or list of scalar variables.** This is done by writing the base SQL command and adding an INTO clause.
>
> ```
> SELECT select_expressions INTO [STRICT] target FROM ...;
> ```
>
> where target can be a record variable, a row variable, or a comma-separated list of simple variables and record/row fields.
>
> **Note that this interpretation of SELECT with INTO is quite different from PostgreSQL's regular SELECT INTO command, wherein the INTO target is a newly created table. If you want to create a table from a SELECT result inside a PL/pgSQL function, use the syntax CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT.**

---

Either `INSERT INTO SELECT` should be used(append) or `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ...` instead.